# Adding to has_one if text_field != blank or nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a simple has_one relationship setup but I want to add records to Damages table only when the text_field is not blank or nil.  Right now it's adding records that are blank or nil to the other table.

My view:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :damage do |builder| %>    
        <%= builder.label 'Damage' %><br />
        <%= builder.text_field :dam_detail %> 
  <% end %>
```

Packjob Model:

```
class Packjob < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :pj_damage
   has_one :damage
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :damage
end
```

Damage Model:

```
 class Damage < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :dam_detail
    belongs_to :packjob
end
```

How do I allow only non blank or nil values being added?
Is best practice to add logic for this to the helper?

EDIT:

Here's the controller for Packjobs:

```
class PackjobsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /packjobs
  # GET /packjobs.json
  def index
    @packjobs = Packjob.includes(:damage).all
    @packers = Packer.find(:all)
    @rigs = Rig.find(:all, :order => "rig_type_number")


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @packjobs }
    end
  end

  # GET /packjobs/1
  # GET /packjobs/1.json
  def show
    @packjob = Packjob.find(params[:id])
    @packers = Packer.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @packjob }
    end
  end

  # GET /packjobs/new
  # GET /packjobs/new.json
  def new
    @packjob = Packjob.new
    @packers = Packer.find(:all, :conditions => { :p_team => "t" }, :order => "p_name")
    @rigs = Rig.find(:all, :conditions => { :rig_status => "t" }, :order => "rig_type_number")
    @damage = @packjob.build_damage             
    #@book = @author.build_book    

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @packjob }
    end
  end

  # GET /packjobs/1/edit
  def edit
    @packjob = Packjob.find(params[:id])
    @packers = Packer.find(:all, :conditions => { :p_team => "t" }, :order => "p_name")
    @rigs = Rig.find(:all, :conditions => { :rig_status => "t" }, :order => "rig_type_number")
  end

  # POST /packjobs
  # POST /packjobs.json
  def create
    @packjob = Packjob.new(params[:packjob])
    @packers = Packer.find(:all, :conditions => { :p_team => "t" }, :order => "p_name")
    @rigs = Rig.find(:all, :conditions => { :rig_status => "t" }, :order => "rig_type_number")

    respond_to do |format|
      if @packjob.save
        format.html { redirect_to @packjob, notice: 'Packjob was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @packjob, status: :created, location: @packjob }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @packjob.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /packjobs/1
  # PUT /packjobs/1.json
  def update
    @packjob = Packjob.find(params[:id])
    @packers = Packer.find(:all, :conditions => { :p_team => "t" }, :order => "p_name")
    @rigs = Rig.find(:all, :conditions => { :rig_status => "t" }, :order => "rig_type_number")

    respond_to do |format|
      if @packjob.update_attributes(params[:packjob])
        format.html { redirect_to @packjob, notice: 'Packjob was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @packjob.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /packjobs/1
  # DELETE /packjobs/1.json
  def destroy
    @packjob = Packjob.find(params[:id])
    @packjob.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to packjobs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Also the I want the packjob to allow for blanks in damage text_field, I just don't want the records added to the Damages table..

Comment: we need to see your controller for that form.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here.  Am I understanding correctly that you want your `Packjob` to be able to have a `Damage` object, but you don't want that object in the Damages table unless it has a non-nil and non-empty text field?  You can do this for in-memory `Packjob`s but once you want to store this in a database you're going to have to change your architecture to get this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html).  Specifically, you want two things:

1. You want your `Damage` class to validate that `:dam_detail` is not blank or `nil`:

   ```
   class Damage < ActiveRecord::Base
     # ... rest of class here ...
     validates :dam_detail, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 1 }
   end
   ```
2. You want your `Packjob` class to validate that its contained `Damage` object is valid:

   ```
   class Packjob < ActiveRecord::Base
     # ... rest of class here ...
     validates_associated :damage
   end
   ```

I also recommend modifying your database schema to add the restriction that the `dam_detail` field cannot be null.  See [the migrations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for more info.

Comment: wont that force the has_one? I think the problem is that he is creating in the controller vs building and I'm assuming there are times he does not want to create the has_on relation.

Answer (score 0):

Even though its more commonly used for has_many the cocoon gem https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon is great for this. That gem will allow you to build the relation on the fly from the front end. it will also allow you to destroy the relation too.